# Yii: Can't save data into newly added column

Tags: php, yii

In my app, Comment model is rendered partially in Product view.
Everything is alright except that after I added a new column to my comment table, I cannot save data into the new column (named 'ddate').
Even I tried this:

```
$_POST['Comment']['ddate'] = 'something';
$model2->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
$model2->save();
```

but not working!

Comment: maybe you haven't added this new attribute to the model properly, preview your model with gii, and check the differences

Comment: I did it line by line! no result!

Comment: please post your full model code

Comment: use `var_dump($model->getErrors())`, maybe you have errors dadash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$temp = $model->attributes;
$model->setFields($_POST['Comment'];);
$model->ddate  = $_POST['Comment']['ddate'];
if($model->save())
{
    echo "saved";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the attribute as 'safe' in the model, or the form value won't be copied to the model when `$model2->attributes = $_POST['Comment'];` is called.

Example:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('ddate', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

---

If you always want ddate to be the current date/time, it might be better to set it in `beforeSave()` instead:

```
protected function beforeSave() {

    if($this->hasAttribute('ddate') && !isset($this->ddate)) 
        $this->ddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: I did it in the craziest way!
I regenerated it in gii and it worked!
but thanks again :)